# Best place to store access tokens for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I have been searching for a while now and can't seem to find an article stating the best practice in storing access tokens. Sorry this is probably a duplicate...

Obviously I would like it to be persistent so naturally I would think storing it in the database or user's cookies. However I have seen some people say to store it in memcache or session but I don't really know what they mean by that.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you store the session to a cookie, it is better to use the default ActionController::Session::CookieStore, as it is cryptographically signed and encryted.

Storing it in database could be ok, but this would require a db access just to see if user is authenticated and that could lead to performance's issues. Memcache is a good alternative, because being a in-memory key-value store engine improves performance.

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) for reference

Comment: But I thought `session` hash is not persistent. Once the user closes their browser we lose any form of identification.

Comment: Session are stored server-side, so they do not depends on browser. The session id is stored in a cookie on the user's browser and it is persisted as long as the user does not delete it or depending on cookie expiration date. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) for a reference

Comment: "There is one exception, and that is the default and recommended session store - the CookieStore - which stores all session data in the cookie itself (the ID is still available to you if you need it)" It seems that the client stores the information not the server by default....

Comment: I am further confused by this line "# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails g active_record:session_migration")
# Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store" So are they trying to say storing sensitive data should not be done on the server side???

Comment: That line states that session is stored in a cookie, but it is signed and encrypted so very secure. What is still confusing to you?

Comment: Really is just this part "Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default, # which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information " So its suggesting we shouldn't store anything confidential when opting to store information on server side?

Comment: I think that for example you shouldn't store a password in the cookie (this is very confidential!), or credit card info. Session token is ok for cookie - provided that cookie is encrypted and signed